# Read & Write multiple times over the same websocket in go

Tags: json, go, websocket

**First of all, context:**

- I'm fairly new to go, I've take one 5 weeks course, but thats about it.
- I'm all new to networking, and I've been playing around with websockets (in go) for a couple of days.

I'm working in a small team and I've been tasked with developing an IRC-server (in go) using Websockets. In order for me to be able to make sure that the server works, I've written a small testing framework (also in go).

**Now to the problem at hand:**
The problem is in this snippet of code.

```
enc := json.NewEncoder(ws)
creator := g.UserID{Name: _name, UUID: g.GenerateUID(_name + _subject)}
ac := g.DiscussionCreate{Subject: _subject, Creator: creator}
err = enc.Encode(ac) //This encoding IS read by the server.
Log.Err(err, "enc.Encode")

dec := json.NewDecoder(ws)
var disc, empty g.Discussion
err = dec.Decode(&disc)
Log.Err(err, "dec.Decode")

send := g.Message{
    Msg:  "Hello, World!",
    UDID: disc.DiscussionID.UDID,
    UUID: creator.UUID}
err = enc.Encode(send) //This encoding ISN'T read by the server.
Log.Err(err, "enc.Encode")
```

The server reads the first encoded message.
But fails to read the second one.

The first message is read in this function

```
func Create(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    Log.Connection(ws)
    var dc g.DiscussionCreate
    var di g.Discussion

    dec := json.NewDecoder(ws)
    err := dec.Decode(&dc) //Here <-----
    Log.Err(err, "dec.Decode")

    discID := g.DiscussionID{
        Subject: dc.Subject,
        UDID:    g.GenerateUID(time.Now().String())}

    ssUserID := g.SSUserID{
        Name: dc.Creator.Name,
        UUID: dc.Creator.UUID,
        WS:   ws}

    disc := g.SSDiscussion{
        DiscussionID: discID,
        Participants: []g.SSUserID{ssUserID}}

    g.LivingDiscussions = append(g.LivingDiscussions, disc)
    Log.Activity("Discussion", "Created", disc.DiscussionID.Subject)

    di = g.Discussion{
        DiscussionID: discID,
        Participants: []g.UserID{dc.Creator}}

    enc := json.NewEncoder(ws)
    err = enc.Encode(di)
    Log.Err(err, "enc.Encode")

    go g.LivingDiscussions[len(g.LivingDiscussions)-1].Participants[0].Listen()
}
```

And the second message is read in the go routine started in the last line of the function above.

```
func (ssUserID *SSUserID) Listen() {
    lastMessage := time.Now().Second()
    dec := json.NewDecoder(ssUserID.WS)
    empty := ""
    var msg Message
    for (lastMessage + ConnTimeout) > time.Now().Second() {
        if err := dec.Decode(&msg); err == nil { //Here  <-----
            Messages <- msg
            lastMessage = time.Now().Second()
        } else if err := dec.Decode(&empty); err == nil {
            lastMessage = time.Now().Second()
        }
    }
}
```

Why wont the server read the second message?
And how do i solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: It appears that you are using the [buggy](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket#gorilla-websocket-compared-with-other-packages) x/net/websocket package.  Consider using [Gorilla](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket) and starting with Gorilla's  [chat example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x/net/websocket package closes the connection on return from the handler. To fix this, do the work in the handler function instead of starting a goroutine:

```
g.LivingDiscussions[len(g.LivingDiscussions)-1].Participants[0].Listen()
```